# Moving ViewElement in Relative Layout from one position to other Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to move a image from one label to another label within relative layout. I have used img.TranslateTo() where in I have passed X,Y parameters as label.X, Label.Y. I am getting the animation but its far from my label's position.

Comment: Could you show your code and if at any rate possible screenshots of your UI, and maybe a sketch of the desired outcome?

Comment: Could you post both `.xaml` and `.cs` code?